# Why won't one of my components work in my React Native project?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm teaching myself React Native and as of now, I've ran into a minor problem.

I want `<KeyboardAvoidingView/>` to push the 2 input boxes up so that the user can see what they're typing but my code isn't doing that.  It isn't even showing what user is typing.  The user must press `Next` on the keyboard they can see what they typed.  Also, what I press `Next`, it doesn't go to the next input box.

Here's `App.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import BackGround from './components/BackGround';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.back}>
                <BackGround/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    back: {
        flex: 1
    }
});
```

Here's `Login.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, TextInput, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, KeyboardAvoidingView} from 'react-native';

class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={"padding"} style={styles.container}>
                <View>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.input}
                        returnKeyType={"next"}
                        keyboardType={"email-address"}
                        autoCorrect={false}
                        placeholder={"Email"}
                    />

                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.input}
                        returnKeyType={"go"}
                        placeholder={"Password"}
                        secureTextEntry
                    />

                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text style={styles.loginAndCA}>Login</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text style={styles.loginAndCA}>Create Account</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        padding: 20
    },

    input: {
        backgroundColor: '#DAE5FF',
        // paddingBottom: 20,
        padding: 20,
        paddingHorizontal: 15,
        marginBottom: 10,
        borderRadius: 15,
    },

    loginAndCA: {
        fontSize: 40,
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: 'white',
        fontFamily: 'Bodoni 72 Smallcaps',
        paddingHorizontal: 10
    }
});

export default Login;
```

Here's `BackGround.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Image, View, Text} from 'react-native';
import Login from './Login';

class BackGround extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.first}>
                <Image style={styles.container} source={require('../pictures/smoke.jpg')}>                      
                        <Login/>
                </Image>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: null,
        height: null,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    },

    first: {
        flex: 1
    },

    second: {
       paddingTop: 290 // Moves both <TextInput> boxes down.
    },

});

export default BackGround;
```

Comment: Good question, I couldn't get KeyboardAvoidingView to work earlier on today so I resorted to using the react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view package. I'm very interested in seeing a solution.

Comment: @Dan I've tried a laundry list of things to rectify this problem, can't figure this out.  It seems so simple.